# Using regular expressions to denote the opener of nestedExpr

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to use pyparsing to match nested expressions. Without having to specify the content expression, is there a way to use regular expressions to define the opener?

My opener consists of two tokens A and B. These two tokens may or may not be separated by whitespace and newline characters.

I am able to create a pyparsing expression for the opener when specifying a content rule. However is there a way to do this without specifying a content rule? Alternatively, how can I specify a rule to ignore content?

```
opener = Word('A') + ZeroOrMore(' ') + ZeroOrMore('\n') + Word('B')
closer = 'END'
content_rule = SkipTo(opener | closer)


pat = nestedExpr(opener=opener, closer=closer, content=content_rule) 


for x in pat.scanString(data):
    print x
```

Context:
I am trying to extract if-blocks from source code files. So I will need a way of extracting nested expressions. This requires me to specify:

1. An opener that consists of multiple tokens which can be separated by white-space ('if {')
2. A way for the closer to match only the closing tags that correspond to the opener. i.e. Closers for other blocks are the same than for the if-block. Consider loops for example: while () {}. I am not sure if this is possible however.

Comment: We might be able to help more if you give more context about what you're trying to match and why, and the way in which the code you show doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and help.

Comment: It is not necessary to show the optional whitespace in your opener expression - that is a significant difference between pyparsing and regex. You could just write opener as `opener = Word('A') + Word('B')`. Also, are you sure Word is the correct class here? Word('A') will match "A", "AAAA', "AAAAAAAAA", or any group of consecutive "A"s. If you just want to match "A", use Literal class, not the Word class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I am not sure if this is possible however.

It isn't, at least for general C code. For example:

```
if (a) {
    char a = '}';
}
```

There's no good way for your parser to know (as opposed to guessing) that the first close curly-brace is not intended to close the if statement without actually parsing the interior. (Also comments, double-quoted strings, etc. Not to mention curly-brace-less ifs!)

If you're confident the interior only has balanced curly braces, and you only want top-level if statements, my suggestion would be to do something like this (untested, but hopefully it gets the idea across):

```
pat = Literal('if') + nestedExpr("{", "}")
```

If you need nested ifs, you might be able to do something like:

```
expression = Forward()
if_statement = Literal('if') + nestedExpr("{", "}", expression)
expression << ZeroOrMore(Or(if_statement, Regex('.')))
```

Comment: Thanks. Using Regex without the content rule fails (hence my question on how to specify a rule to ignore everything):

ValueError: opening and closing arguments must be strings if no content expression is given

Comment: Ah, ok, that would be helpful to add to your question.

Comment: FYI - nestedExpr implicitly guards against openers and closers occurring inside quoted strings. If comment expression is provided (by virtue of calling `ignore(commentExpr)`), openers and closers inside comments are also properly handled.

Comment: Also, if the openers and closers are strings as you show in pat (not exprs like the OP is asking), then the content arg is not required. so your original `pat` expr could be written as just `pat = nestedExpr("{","}")`.

Comment: If you find that you are Or'ing in things like `Regex(".")` in order to skip over text that is not defined in your parser, you may have better results switching from using parseString to searchString or scanString.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks for the clarifications. (You can probably tell I'm not actually familiar with pyparsing.) I can incorporate them inline, unless you'd rather make an answer of them.

Comment: @JesseRusak - I am thrilled to see others chiming in on any questions related to pyparsing, and your stab at making a pyparsing Forward expression was nicely done. I will do a little cleanup, such as changing Word to Literal as I mentioned in the original post. But I'd rather comment on your chosen answer than to post another and snipe your checkmark points!